# How to convert this data into the given format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I was trying to make the data I'm having with me to a much more readable and easily understandable format. But I was stuck with it. is it possible to convert it into a readable format?

The data I'm having is in the format below

```
[
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Food Truck: The Vegan"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/02/2022 16:00:00"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/02/2022 21:00:00"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/02/2022"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/03/2022 16:00:00"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/03/2022 21:00:00"
          },
          {
            "v": "06/03/2022"
          }
        ]
      }}]
```

I want to convert it to a much more readable format like the example given below.

```
        {
        "name": "Food Truck: The Vegan Table",
        "start_date": "06/02/2022 16:00:00",
        "end_date": "06/02/2022 21:00:00",
        "date": "06/02/2022"
        },
        {
        "name": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs",
        "start_date": "06/03/2022 16:00:",
        "end_date": "06/03/2022 21:00:00",
        "date": "06/03/2022"
        }
]

How should I do this in javascript?
```

Comment: since there's no explicit semanthic in your source data, how do you discern which date is "start_date" and "end_date" for example? are those objects in the arrays ordered? so that the first one is always the name, the second one is always the start_date and so on?

Comment: probably a nested for loop

Comment: @Bravo you're on a roll with loop suggestions.

Comment: @pilchard - but, I'm right :p

Comment: @diego-de-vita Yes It's always in that order

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Object.fromEntries+mdn&oq=Object.from&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i61.4520j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with a separate `keys` array to map over your array and reformat each nested array.

```js
const input = [{ "c": [{ "v": "Food Truck: The Vegan" }, { "v": "06/02/2022 16:00:00" }, { "v": "06/02/2022 21:00:00" }, { "v": "06/02/2022" }] }, { "c": [{ "v": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs" }, { "v": "06/03/2022 16:00:00" }, { "v": "06/03/2022 21:00:00" }, { "v": "06/03/2022" }] }]

const keys = ['name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'date'];

const result = input.map(({ c }) => Object.fromEntries(
  keys.map((key, i) => [key, c[i].v])
));

console.log(result)
```

Or using some long-winded [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). (arguably the most descriptive...)

```js
const input = [{ "c": [{ "v": "Food Truck: The Vegan" }, { "v": "06/02/2022 16:00:00" }, { "v": "06/02/2022 21:00:00" }, { "v": "06/02/2022" }] }, { "c": [{ "v": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs" }, { "v": "06/03/2022 16:00:00" }, { "v": "06/03/2022 21:00:00" }, { "v": "06/03/2022" }] }]

const result = input.map((
  { c:
    [
      { v: name },
      { v: start_date },
      { v: end_date },
      { v: date }
    ]
  }
) => (
  {
    name,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    date
  }
));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the raw data and restructure it in the way you desire. Since there are no proper keys for raw data, if the order or index is always the same, you can do it in the following way.

```js
var data = [{
        "c": [{
                "v": "Food Truck: The Vegan"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/02/2022 16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/02/2022 21:00:00"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/02/2022"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [{
                "v": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/03/2022 16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/03/2022 21:00:00"
            },
            {
                "v": "06/03/2022"
            }
        ]
    }
];


function processData(_raw) {
    var processed = [];

    _raw.forEach(_item => {
        processed.push({
            "name": _item.c[0].v,
            "start_date": _item.c[1].v,
            "end_date": _item.c[2].v,
            "date": _item.c[3].v
        });
    });
    return processed;
}

console.log(processData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method (`format` in the snippet) to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the elements of your array:

```js
const keys = `name,start_date,end_date,date`.split(`,`);
const format = (acc, obj, i) => ( {...acc, [keys[i]]: obj.v} );
const dataFormatted = getData().map( v => v.c.reduce(format, {}) );

console.log(dataFormatted);

function getData() {
  return [ {
  "c": [
    { "v": "Food Truck: The Vegan" },
    { "v": "06/02/2022 16:00:00" },
    { "v": "06/02/2022 21:00:00" },
    { "v": "06/02/2022" } ]
  }, {
  "c": [
    { "v": "Food Truck: Lob Dogs" },
    { "v": "06/03/2022 16:00:00" },
    { "v": "06/03/2022 21:00:00" }, 
    { "v": "06/03/2022" } ]
  } ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const data = [{c: [{v: 'Food Truck: The Vegan',},{v: '06/02/2022 16:00:00',},{v: '06/02/2022 21:00:00',},{v: '06/02/2022',},],},{c: [{v: 'Food Truck: Lob Dogs',},{v: '06/03/2022 16:00:00',},{v: '06/03/2022 21:00:00',},{v: '06/03/2022',},],},]

const keys = ['name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'date']

const result = data.map(
  ({ c }) => c.reduce((a, { v }, i) => (a[keys[i]] = v, a), {})
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rawData is always the same format i would say something like this

```
const rawData = [
  {
    c: [
      {
        v: "Food Truck: The Vegan"
      },
      {
        v: "06/02/2022 16:00:00"
      },
      {
        v: "06/02/2022 21:00:00"
      },
      {
        v: "06/02/2022"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    c: [
      {
        v: "Food Truck: Lob Dogs"
      },
      {
        v: "06/03/2022 16:00:00"
      },
      {
        v: "06/03/2022 21:00:00"
      },
      {
        v: "06/03/2022"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const format = ["name", "start_date", "end_date", "date"];

const formattedResult = rawData.map(({ c }) => Object.fromEntries(
  format.map((key, i) => [key, c[i].v])
));

console.log(formattedResult);
```